# I want to install wifi card, but my additional drives is empty

Tags: wireless

Today, I install Ubuntu 14.04 version. And I want to connect my wifi. But the system cannot find my wifi card in the additional drivers, by the way my additional drivers window is empty. How to solve this problem?

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

shows ...

```
Realtek Semiconduct Co., ltd. RTL8192EE PCI e wireless Neteork Adapter[10ec:818b]
```

Comment: Please tell us more about your card: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Hi chili555, i put that into terminal, it shows : Realtek Semiconduct Co., ltd. RTL8192EE PCI e wireless Neteork Adapter[10ec:818b]

Comment: @hbdgaf et al -- This isn't a Broadcom card!

Comment: @chili555 Do you have a better question? I have reopened this.

Comment: @Seth- I have an answer for Jizhou which I shall post momentarily.

Answer (score 2):

Your device uses the driver rtl8192ee which is not included in Ubuntu 14.04 and must be compiled from source code. Please get a temporary internet connection; ethernet or tethered or however. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8192ee
```

Your wireless should be working now. Please let us know how it goes as we will probably have one more step.

Comment: Oh . When I use this way . My ubuntu was totally corrupt.  Coming with a black screen writing kernel panic-not syncing  fatal exception in interruption.