# Wireless not working at all, thinkpad x240, intel 7260, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, intel, thinkpad

I just bought a brand new Lenovo Thinkpad x240. After installing Ubuntu 14.04 everything there is no sign of WiFi.

The card is intel 7260. It connects normally through a cable DHCP.

after "iwlist scan" i get

```
wwan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

My driver info:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 28:d2:44:9a:3b:73
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.6-3 ip=172.16.1.70 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:60 memory:f0600000-f061ffff memory:f063e000-f063efff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0400000-f0403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wwan0
       serial: 42:e9:c4:a8:66:4c
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_mbim driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC MBIM link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to install wifi card, but my additional drives is empty](http://askubuntu.com/questions/523397/i-want-to-install-wifi-card-but-my-additional-drives-is-empty)

Comment: I don't think your wireless card is Intel 7260, it's **RTL8192EE** in your `sudo lshw -C network` output.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/523397/i-want-to-install-wifi-card-but-my-additional-drives-is-empty/523689#523689

Comment: The method explained on this link crashed my ubuntu. a black screen writing kernel panic-not syncing fatal exception in interruption, apears

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile and load rtl8192ee driver manually. After that I could get my wifi working. But the ethernet controller i218-LM still does not work.

Comment: Please expand your answer, for example how to compile the driver manually.